# How send HSV value to color picker?

Tags: python

How send HSV value to color picker in Blender from Python console? 
By default we can send only RGB :(

Comment: How about using a script with a function that converts HSV to RGB? You would have to execute the script instead of entering the command in the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [mathutils.Color](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/mathutils.html#mathutils.Color) type to convert HSV to RGB:

```
from mathutils import Color

c = Color()
c.hsv = 0.0833, 0.4, 0.5

print(c)
# roughly Color((0.5, 0.4, 0.3))
```

If you want to assign the color to a RGBA property (4 floats), you need to either do:

```
bpy.context.object.color = c.r, c.g, c.b, 1.0 # 1.0 is alpha
```

or a bit ugly looking tuple concatenation:

```
bpy.context.object.color = c[:] + (1.0,)
```

Alternatively, import the Python standard library module `colorsys` and use its conversion functions:

```
import colorsys

colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(0.0833, 0.4, 0.5)
# (0.5, 0.39996, 0.3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much CoDEmanX! I have one more question:
How refresh color picker element, after I set new value?

Comment: If it doesn't update automatically, flag it to let Blender refresh it by calling [Region.tag_redarw()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.Region.html?highlight=region.tag_redraw#bpy.types.Region.tag_redraw) on the editor region where the property is shown in.